# javascript,css,html dropdown menu mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used javascript on a menu so that when I mouseover it should drop down. But instead of only the menu dropping down, the footer and the menus are coming down too.

**CSS:**

```
.navmenu  {position:relative;float:left;cursor: pointer;margin-right:2px;width:200px;min-width:200px;}
.navmenu a{top:0px;left:0px;padding: 0;color: #000;text-decoration: none;position:relative;}
nav .wrapper{width:150px;min-height:128px;display:block;}
ul.subnav {top:0px;padding: 0px 5px 5px 15px;margin: 0px;list-style: none;position: relative;max-width: 150px; width: 150px;  left: 0; display: none;z-index:150;  }
ul.subnav li{padding:5px; width:120px;text-decoration: none;}
.imagem1{top:0px;left:-15px;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;z-index:150;}
.imagem3{top:0px;left:-15px;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;z-index:150;}
.imagem2{top:-3px;left:-3px;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;z-index:150;}
.imagem4{top:-3px;left:-20px;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;z-index:150;}
.imagem5{top:1px;left:-44px;margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;z-index:180;}
.menuname{min-height:40px;z-index:150;}
.menuname img {border:0;}
#placaparque{left:20px;top:-17px;z-index:150;}
#placainfo{left:-15px;top:-10px;z-index:150;}
#placacons{left:-15px;top:-5px;z-index:150;}
#placaactiv{left:-10px;top:-8px;z-index:150;}
#placaanim{left:-65px;top:-6px;z-index:150;}
1#sub1{left:0px;top:0;}
1#sub3{left:0px;z-index:150;}
#fundo1{position:relative;background-image:url('images/fundo.png');left:38px;width:150px;min-height:128px;}
#fundo2{position:relative;background-image:url('images/fundo.png');left:0px;width:150px;min-height:128px;}
#fundo3{position:relative;background-image:url('images/fundo.png');left:-10px;width:150px;min-height:128px;}
#fundo4{position:relative;background-image:url('images/fundo.png');left:-10px;width:150px;min-height:128px;}
#fundo5{position:relative;background-image:url('images/fundo.png');left:-10px;width:150px;min-height:128px;}

#parq{left:-20px;}
#acti{left:-30px;}
#info{left:-65px;}
#cons{left:-110px;}
#anim{z-index:100;left:-155px;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="mainMenu">
    <div id="parq" class="navmenu" >
        <div " id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
            <div id="fundo1" class="fundo">
                <ul id="sub1" class="subnav">
                    <?php /*wp_list_categories('include=16');*/ ?>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Menu Parque' ) ); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <img class="imagem1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comboioparque.png"/>
        </div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    var divnav = $(this); //menu1
    $("#parq").hover(function () {
        $("#sub1").stop(true, true).delay(200).slideDown(300);
        $(".imagem1").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
    }, function () {
        $(".imagem1").stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
        $("#sub1").stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
});
```

I only want the to menu drop down. I don't want the rest of the menus under and footer coming down too. I know it has something to do with "z-index" but I'm not following.

Can yall help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the HTML and java script?

Comment: Please post those things only relevant to your question, not the entire file!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, notice that you are having an error in this line of the css:

1#sub1{left:0px;top:0;}

it should be like this:

```
#sub1{left:0px;top:0px;} /*and by the way, why have you added a number one before the id??*/
```

You also have an error in this line of the html:

```
<div " id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
```

it should be like this:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
```

in the css of .navmenu  why are you defining a with and ALSO a min-width?? Im not sure if that would validate for W3C...maybe it can cause you css conflicts
If you are calling both of them in order to view it right in IE6 I would recomend you to use a hack for width and for all the other browsers just leave the "min-width".

And finally one curious question: in the jquery, why are you using a .stop method? Why dont you just use an .animate method?? You could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#btn1").click(function(){
  $("#box").animate({height:"300px"});
 });
 $("#btn2").click(function(){
  $("#box").animate({height:"100px"});
 });
});
```

I hope something of all this things may help you. Besides, in the jquery you are ONLY calling the #sub1 and not others so the jquery I think should work well.

If you are still having problems, let us know... because as far as I understand I only found those details.

Regards,

Comment: $(function() {

var divnav = $(this);

//menu1

$("#parq").hover(function(){  
$("#sub1").stop(true, true).delay(200).slideDown(300);
$(".imagem1").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);


}, function(){ 
$(".imagem1").stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(200);
$("#sub1").stop(true, true).slideUp(300); 
  
});

Comment: <nav id="mainMenu">
 <div id="parq" class="navmenu" >
 <div " id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
  <div id="fundo1" class="fundo">
   <ul id="sub1" class="subnav">   
    <?php /*wp_list_categories('include=16');*/ ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Menu Parque' ) ); ?>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <img class="imagem1" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/comboioparque.png"/>
 </div>